# Frequency from vector in R

Tags: r, vector, bar-chart, frequency

A have vector with 84 measured continuous values from 10 to 60. I want to sort that values in groups by 5 (5-10,10-15,15-20...55-60). Then, number of values in each group (group frequency) need to bee plot on barplot. I tried with "cut", but result is factor which I cannot coerce in matrix or vector which are only readable  by bar plots.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this maybe:

```
# Data for reproducible example
set.seed(123)
vec <- sample(10:60, 84, replace = TRUE)

#Create groups by 5
vec2 <- cut(vec, seq(10, 61, by=5), include.lowest = TRUE)

table(vec2)
```

For plotting look at `ggplot2`

Comment: I have measured value, no need for sampling.